# R - drop columns with more than x% of one letter (a,b,h)

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe with genotype/marker data (columns) of several individuals (rows). After changing the allele calls to a, b and h I have a lot of columns remaining that have more than 80% a b or h, which I know are erroneous calls. I was able to remove/drop columns with missing values with

```
mydata1 <- x[which(colMeans(is.na(x)) <= .5)]
```

but I don't seem to be able to remove columns with >80% of a or b (or h - less likely) like Marker2. I have tried the colMeans function and the length function.

```
x <- data.frame("Marker1" = c("a","b","h"), "Marker2" = c("a","a","a"), "Marker3" = c("a","b","NA"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We loop through the columns, get the `table`, find the proportion and check all of them are less than 0.8

```
Filter(function(u) all(prop.table(table(u)) <= 0.8), x)
#    Marker1 Marker3
#1       a       a
#2       b       b
#3       h      NA
```